# Spring3 Security Framework, Where do I set Spring Security Login?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building my first progject with Spring3 Security Framework, Where do I set Spring Security Login??

If I got one of the pages that needs to be login I get this error

Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/MySpring/spring_security_login

My login page is at http://localhost:8080/MySpring/Login/add.html

Comment: Take a look at the Tutorials page of the following blog: http://krams915.blogspot.com/ There's a whole section for Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the sec:form tag in the security setup.  For you, it would be:

`<form-login login-page="/Login/add.html"/>`